# How to avoid changing invalid date in views without error warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know, that the question is quite newbies, but I couldn't find any related answer to my case. Any help will be appreciate.

I have to use a `date_select` tag on view in may app. So the question is how to avoid changing invalid date (e.c., the 30th of February to the 2nd of March), and show an error to user, so that he could correct the date by himself? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, use some kind of custom validation in model like:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  validate :date_is_valid

  def date_is_valid
    if (DateTime.parse(date) rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError
      errors.add(:date, 'must be a valid datetime')
    end
  end
end
```

Cheers!